# PHP Submit button doesn't have any effect (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, html

**I updated the question.**

Since the last code was pretty complex and even after fixing the stuff it didn't work, I executed the below simple code to check if things work. Even this code doesn't work. Whenever I click on the submit button, it again returns a 404 error.

Yes, I placed the PHP code in the body as well to check if this work but it doesn't.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo("Done!!!!");

} else {
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Echo results!</title>

</head>

<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>

<?php
}

?>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The method of your form is `get` not `post`

Comment: In Form method you mentioned `get` method and you are accessing data by using `S_POST`.

Comment: Most likely problem is that you have put another form around your submit buttons so your main form is not being submitted. Also you are sending a $_GET request but using $_POST to retrieve the data which won't work.

Comment: Test against the name attribute on the submit button, not its id.

Comment: Nesting other interactive elements such as `input` into `a` is invalid HTML btw.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['button_create'])) {
your button name is Submit

Comment: What does 'I can't use POST as PhpStorm POST code doesn't work.' mean?

Comment: I changed the code to a much easier one, details are present in the question itself.

Comment: Are you using the built-in PhpStorm web server or do you run a separate Apache?

Comment: Can we see the rendered html?  Specifically the action attribute.  Which version of PhpStorm?

Comment: @VladLuchansky I'm using XAMPP Apache server with PHPStorm in built web server.

Comment: @Progrock the HTML code is displayed in the question, it's the same. I'm using PHPStorm version 2018.1.2

Comment: As you have an alternative Php server there, you could try it in XAMPP, bypassing PhpStorm's webserver.  Same result?

Comment: @KarlChertoff I asked for the resulting HTML (after Php interpretation).

Comment: @Progrock the resulting HTML once I load up the page is just the button displayed. Whenever I submit, the 404 error loads.

Comment: @Progrock Whenever I use XAMPP's web server as default, 'Object not found' error returns.

Comment: It sounds as if your form action is posting to bad place.  I was after the action attribute, after Php processing.

Comment: @Progrock I have found the issue. After using the XAMPP webserver as only **default**, it worked. POST couldn't work without XAMPP webserver being default. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `button_create` as name of the submit button

Comment: like i put in my comment but then he needs to change the action of the form from GET to Post

Comment: @tuckbloor you mean like my comment.  Anyway, this is only a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

if(isset($_POST['button_create'])) {

<td><input type="submit" name="button_create" id="button_create" value="Create Table!"></td>
```

change these lines see how you go from there

Comment: I tried to do so. Look at the below code, I just created a simple page to check if basic code works. But even in my below code, whenever I click on Submit button, it displays a 404 error. `<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo("Done!!!!");

} else {
?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Echo results!</title>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>

    </form>

    <?php
}

?>

</body>


</html>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong here, method should be POST instead of GET. The name attribute of text fields should be used when receiving the values. The submit button name should be used to check whether the button is clicked or not. See the example given below.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ex1 = $_POST['ex1'];
    $ex2 = $_POST['ex2'];
    echo $ex1 . " " . $ex2;
  }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  Ex1 value: <input name="ex1" type="text" />
  Ex2 value: <input name="ex2" type="text" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Echo results!
>
> ```
> <?php
>     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
>         echo("Done!!!!");
>     } else {
>
> ?>
>     <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
>         <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
>     </form>
>
> <?php
>     }
> ?>
> ```

this is for your updated question

Comment: It's pretty much same as mine. Even while using the code, 404 error appears. I guess PHPStorm doesn't allow POST method? Because when I try GET method, everything works.